# NuGet: where is AForge.Video.FFMPEG

Tags: c#, git, ffmpeg, aforge

Good day. I want to use `AForge.Video.FFMPEG` in my project. So, i try to find it on the NuGet. But i'm not found it here.

So, here it exists: https://code.google.com/archive/p/aforge/downloads

But, if i want to restore it automatically from nuget (after git clone and rebuild), it's not allowed in this case? Only store this dll in project and push/fetch it always?

Answer (score 5):

You can use Accord.Video.FFMPEG

Comment: This is correct. Accord.Video merged with old AForge keeping the compatibility so using this package requires no actual adaptation

Answer (score 4):

Install from Package Manager Console using:

`Install-Package Accord.Video.FFMPEG -Version 3.8.0`

Answer (score 0):

You can install it with `Install-Package AForge.Video.FFMPEG.lib` from Package Manager Console. You can find it in Tools -> Library Package Manager -> Package Manager Console.

Comment: Doesn't work now... gives error 
Install-Package : Unable to find package 'AForge.Video.FFMPEG.lib'

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the author of the library haven't provided NuGet package for it. But you can create a package by yourself and host it either at official nuget.org feed or your own feed.

Also, may be package name is not exactly that one you are expecting. Look carefully through list of AForge packages at official feed. May be it's there but with not expected name https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=AForge